# Add "UIView" in "UINavigationBar" behind "LargeTitleText" title

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uinavigationbar

I create a Project in Xcode as "UINavigationController" with "Use Large Title" option for a bigger NavigationBar.

In background of the title (Example: Testtitle here...) i try to add a "UIView" with background image (comes later, as example red colored).

But the `setFrame`heigh from `500px` are ignored.

My Question:
How i can add a "UIView" or "UIImageView" in the Background of the "UINavigationBar". The final image ( i will set) has a size from 50x50px and should behind the title. **Not** on top.

I wouldn't use "leftbarbuttonitem" or "rightbarbuttonitem". This button's are on top side. Thats not a option.

Please see the Screenshot as attachment.

Thanks --Christian

[image]

Comment: can use `navigationItem.titleView` to set custom view.

Comment: Have you see my code ? I have set ```navigationItem.titleView```.

Comment: Add `UILabel` on your custom title view

Comment: This is not working